# UISegmentedControl rendered completely wrong when used with images and rendered correctly when used with text

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6

I have this app compiled for iOS 6. This is a code upgraded from iOS 4.3 and was working fine there.

After creating a segmented control, its icons are just the alpha channel and the control is transparent.

This is how I create it

```
// images is a NSArray of images. I have confirmed. 
// All images are OK and are loading fine on this array. 
// Images have alpha channel. They are basically solid
// rounded icons with shadows surrounded by transparent pixels
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:images];
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:selector(change:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
```

This is how I see the control. Notice the blurred blue right border that corresponds to the icon shadow on the alpha channel. Also, another problem is this being blue. I never adjusted any blue color on this control. This was simply working fine on iOS 4.3.

Any clues?

---

EDIT: as soon as I replace the images with text, the segmented controlled is rendered correctly: opaque and no blue ever. Now the WTF level increased.

I have created a sample project with 3 red images that for some WTF factor show blue. Download the project here:  http://www.fileswap.com/dl/RVf7UuwKhf/

[image]

Comment: Sorry to ask but are you running this on xcode 5 or older versions?

Comment: Xcode 5. I have uploaded a sample project that shows the problem... here: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/RVf7UuwKhf/

Comment: Your project seems to be working [fine here](http://cl.ly/image/3Z41312p2s1y). That being said your problem seems to be that the images for some reason are treated as templates by iOS7 and hence the blue color (which is your global `tint` color)

Comment: see? it is not working for you. You are seeing the letters in blue. Look at the images. they are red. I have tried in Xcode 4. Same problem but I think Xcode 5 changed the project and now Xcode 4 is rendering it wrongly too.

Comment: I have opened the original file on Xcode 4.63. The toolbar appears so fine that hurts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS7 has introduced a new option for images (`UIImageRenderingMode`). What this option does is to specify whether an image is to be treated as a template or not.

If the image is on template 'mode' then the non transparent part is tinted (the default color for `tint` is the global one to match your app tint everywhere and hence provide a coherent theme on controls overall).

The solution is simply to specify your images as `original` instead of `template` like this:

```
UIImage *a = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ITEAM-icon157.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIImage *b = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ITEAM-icon159.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIImage *c = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ITEAM-icon160.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Of course, in case you just wanted to have a red `segmentedControl` with red icons, you could just set the `tintColor` of the control (without specifying rendering mode on images like above) like this:

```
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

As a final note, there is a third option called `UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic`, where the image is automatically treated as template/normal based on the context where the image is used. Although Apple doesn't clarify how the context is determined, I would expect it to choose `template` for controls and `normal` for `UIImageView`s etc.

You can find the [relevant documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4).

Comment: ARE YOU KIDDING ME???!?!?!?!?! This is why I hate all apple docs... a reference to that should be added to the part where you define images to use on the segmented controller. I love Apple because the default is template, just to annoy the programmer. But I see a problem here: this app is compiled for 6.0. So I will have to have two ways of loading the images, one for iOS 6 and one for iOS 7.... Thanks Apple.

Comment: @RubberDuck Yes that is correct, I'm afraid that you'll have to check for the iOS version and fork accordingly if you want to support previous versions.

Comment: Using your answer the images are now correct but the toolbar is still transparent with blue dividers (for God's sake Apple). Adding a tint and a background color to the segmented control solved both problems.... That makes me think: what other APIs from previous versions does iOS 7 not respect? grrrrrr!

Comment: Yes that is expected behavior since the `UISegmentedControl` on iOS7 have a transparent bg by default. Glad you solved your problem :)

Comment: yes, but if the app is compiled for iOS 6, iOS 7 should respect the render mode back then. This is stupid. Ah, and if the bg of UISegmentedControls are now transparent, why there is no mention to that to their awful docs?

Comment: The thing is that `UIRenderingMode` was not available on iOS6, it is a new API. [This guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/) may help you regarding UI transition to iOS7